# Code runs but does not meet preconditions in type contract

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

In the code there is a helper function called clean_up and below is my code. I was wondering what do i need to fix, add, or remove to make it work.

```
def clean_up(s):
    """ (str) -> str

    Return a new string based on s in which all letters have been
    converted to lowercase and punctuation characters have been stripped 
    from both ends. Inner punctuation is left untouched. 

    >>> clean_up('Happy Birthday!!!')
    'happy birthday'
    >>> clean_up("-> It's on your left-hand side.")
    " it's on your left-hand side"
    """

    punctuation = """!"',;:.-?)([]<>*#\n\t\r"""
    result = s.lower().strip(punctuation)
    return result


##########  Complete the following functions. ############

def type_token_ratio(text):
    """ (list of str) -> float

    Precondition: text is non-empty. Each str in text ends with \n and
    text contains at least one word.

    Return the Type Token Ratio (TTR) for this text. TTR is the number of
    different words divided by the total number of words.

    >>> text = ['James Fennimore Cooper\n', 'Peter, Paul, and Mary\n',
        'James Gosling\n']
    >>> type_token_ratio(text)
    0.8888888888888888
    """ 

    # To do: Fill in this function's body to meet its specification.

    distinctwords = dict()
    words = 0
    for line in text.splitlines():
        line = line.strip().split()
        for word in line:
            words+=1
            if word in distinctwords:
                distinctwords[word]+=1
            else:
                distinctwords[word]=1
    TTR= len(distinctwords)/words
    return TTR
```

Comment: What is going wrong?

Comment: I asked my instructor but he did not explain to me, he says make it so it meets the precondition, but my code runs so i am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code would not even run,  `for line in text.splitlines()` tries to split a list, you need to iterate over the list of words called `text` that is passed in , using [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) will also be more efficient:

```
 def type_token_ratio(text):
    from collections import defaultdict
    distinctwords = defaultdict(int)
    for words in text: # get each string
        words = clean_up(words) # clean the string 
        for word in words.split(): # split into individual words
            distinctwords[word] += 1 # increase the count for each word
    TTR = len(distinctwords) / sum(distinctwords.values()) #  sum(distinctwords.values()) will give total amount of words
    return TTR
```